# How can I create an automatic scrollable label in Kivy?

Tags: android, kivy, kivy-language

I am developing an application that has some buttons on the top with a scrollable `Label` on the bottom. I want to have the scrollable label automatically scrolling from right to left similar to what one may see on the News.

```html
<marquee>N e w s</marquee>
```

I know how to make a scrollable label but I'm not sure how to move it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a scrollable label there's a small piece of code usable directly from `kv` lang. First set the `size_hint_x` to `None`, so that it can be scaled up to the width of `texture_size`.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
Builder.load_string('''
<Spacer@Widget>:
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 800

<ScrollLabel>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        size_hint_x: None
        width: self.minimum_width
        Spacer:
        Label:
            size_hint_x: None
            text: 'l or emi psum '*100
            width: self.texture_size[0]
        Spacer:
''')
class ScrollLabel(ScrollView): pass
scroll = ScrollLabel(scroll_y=-1)
marquee = Animation(scroll_x=1, duration=100.0)
marquee.start(scroll)
runTouchApp(scroll)
```

And to make it scroll just use [`Animation`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.animation.html). You can also use `Widget` as a spacer, so that your text appeared visually like the html `marquee` tag i.e. scrolling into an empty space, and not scrolling already visible text.

Comment: And to have this run over and over and over again I would just need a while True loop? Or is there a better way to handle that?

Comment: @Nithishbn `while True` will freeze the app, you need to use clock, or just try to implement it in `on_scroll` event (in ScrollView), so that when it reaches `scroll_x >= desired_value` then you set the `scroll_x` to let's say `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the top-level layout a ScrollView this following like:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">  
</ScrollView>
```

If you want to scrollview in detail, connect to this site:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Yep, not at all. Notice there's no `java` tag, although people tend to use even `android` for Kivy as it supports it.